# SQL - For Each loop in a query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm not sure what the best title of my question would be, but I'll explain my problem/question the best below:

I'm using the following query, where I filter on a workorder, and I gather all the history of it, which I would need to shown on my report:

```
select a.name, d.data, h.started, e.name, * from wshhistory h
join asset a
on a.uid = h.assetid 
join wshfld d
on h.uid = d.wshhistid
join fielddefinition f
on d.flddefid = f.uid
join enumlookup e
on h.assetstatus = e.uid
where h.shdid = '43FEB092-D3B1-4008-9C44-A3A249987849' order by a.name, h.started asc
```

My result is fine, but...

[image]

What I would need is only 1 row (the last/top one) of each (unique) asset, and the other rows all as column, so that we only have 1 row for each asset.
So that my report looks like:

[image]

In vb.net I would fix this with a for each loop going through all the assets, but with SQL my knowledge is limited, and I have no idea on how to solve this in a query.

Any idea?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Comment: If I would group by name (or asset id), then I get the message:
Column 'asset.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

If I would remove all those selection criteria, and go with * then I still get the same error message, but with another column ('wshhistory.uid')

Comment: If you are grouping you need to group by all columns that are not aggregated. And you should avoid using select * anyway, name the columns explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce the output you stated you want you can use conditional aggregation. Something like this.

```
select a.name
    , min(case when d.data = 'Pre Use' then d.data end) as PreUse
    , min(case when d.data = 'Connected' then d.data end) as Connected
    , min(case when d.data = 'Let Go' then d.data end) as LetGo
    , min(case when d.data = 'Disconnected' then d.data end) as Disconnected
from wshhistory h
join asset a on a.uid = h.assetid 
join wshfld d on h.uid = d.wshhistid
join fielddefinition f on d.flddefid = f.uid
join enumlookup e on h.assetstatus = e.uid
where h.shdid = '43FEB092-D3B1-4008-9C44-A3A249987849' 
group by a.name
order by a.name
```

Comment: This works for his mock up to the results he wants, but it doesn't work with the select all (*) in his query. I like using windows functions for this (i.e. row_number), so you can bring back all the columns for the first record.

Comment: @KeithL I agree but in the desired results it is pretty clear they don't need every column.

Comment: The * was for some extra info, but not for what I wanted on the report.
So this is indeed what I want/needed.  Sorry for the confusion.

Thanks a bunch, you don't want to know how much time I waisted on this, and how much time you've just saved me! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a pivot:

```
WITH A AS(
SELECT a.name , d.data , h.started 
FROM wshhistory h
    join asset a
    on a.uid = h.assetid 
    join wshfld d
    on h.uid = d.wshhistid
    join fielddefinition f
    on d.flddefid = f.uid
    join enumlookup e
    on h.assetstatus = e.uid

WHERE h.shdid = '43FEB092-D3B1-4008-9C44-A3A249987849' 
)
SELECT * FROM a

PIVOT(MAX(startdate) FOR data IN ([Pre Use],[Connected],[Let Go],[Disconnected])) AS MaxStarted
```

Since you haven't created some data for us I can't test it out but it should probably work :)